# Classifying abelian groups of order $56$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

This is an exercise from Dummit and Foote which asks me to show that the number of abelian groups of order $56$ are $3$ upto isomorphism

However I am getting $4$. I am not able to understand which one of them is isomorphic to the  other.

The groups I am getting are:

1. $$\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_7} \cong \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_{14}}$$
2. $$\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_4} \times \mathbb{Z_7} \cong \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_{28}}$$
3. $$\mathbb{Z_4} \times \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_7} \cong \mathbb{Z_4} \times \mathbb{Z_{14}}$$
4. $$\mathbb{Z_8} \times \mathbb{Z_7} \cong  \mathbb{Z_{56}}$$

Comment: 2 and 3 are isomorphic to each other.

Comment: Try the map $(a, b, c) \mapsto (b, a, c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groups 2 and 3 are isomorphic via the isomorphism

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_7 &\to \Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_7,\\
(x,y,z)&\mapsto (y,x,z).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

3. Must be isomorphic to one of the other because 4 doesn't divide 14